# Cannot find gem after bundle install

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm trying to setup my environment to do development on Travis CI's [dpl](https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl) project.

I installed `rbenv` to manage my Ruby versions and I use Ruby 2.2.3.

Then I do `bundle install` and the gems are installed.

Then when I try to do `bundle exec rake` I get this error:

```
Could not find CFPropertyList-2.2.8 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

This gem is installed. Can you tell me why it is not found by Bundler?

Here is a gist of the output of my commands: https://gist.github.com/cotsog/7bb87c84a636bcd3de65

Thanks for your help!

**Update:**

Additional info about my environment:

```
$ which ruby
/Users/me/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ which bundler
/usr/bin/bundler
$ ruby --version                                                                                                     
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14]
$ bundler --version
Bundler version 1.10.6
```

Comment: can you post the output for "bundle config", "env | grep GEM_HOME" and "env | grep GEM_PATH"  ?

Comment: also min while take a look at this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179568/bundle-exec-complains-about-gem-not-being-installed-even-after-bundle-instal